# Jsonobject + Image Multipart AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, multipartform-data

We are trying to send multi-part request to server using AFNetworking. We need to send one JSON object and two image files. The following is the curl request for same.

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/Circle/restapi/offer/add -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "offerDTO={"code": null,"name": "Merry X'Mas - 1","remark": "25% discount on every purchase","validityDate": "22-12-2014","domainCode": "DO - 1","merchantCode": "M-4","isApproved": false,"discountValue": 25,"discountType": "PERCENTAGE"};type=application/json" -F "image=@Team Page.png;type=image/png" -F "letterhead=@Team Page.png;type=image/png"`

I know this should be fairly easy as I've implemented the server as well as Android code for same. And my friend is working on iOS part of this. Also I searched a lot on google, but did not get anything useful.

### Edit

Here is the code that we tried:

```
UIImage *imageToPost = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);

offerDTO = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[offerDTO setObject(angry)"" forKey:@"code"];
[offerDTO setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing"] forKey:@"discountDiscription"];
[offerDTO setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"] forKey:@"remark"];
[offerDTO setObject:@"07-05-2015" forKey:@"validityDate"];
[offerDTO setObject:@"C-7" forKey:@"creatorCode"];
[offerDTO setObject:@"M-1" forKey:@"merchantCode"];
[offerDTO setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"isApproved"];
[offerDTO setObject:@"2.4" forKey:@"discountValue"];
[offerDTO setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FREE"] forKey:@"discountType"];

NSURL *urlsss = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serverurl:8180"];
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:urlsss];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                    path:@"/restapi/offer/add" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                    {
                                        NSData *myData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:offerDTO
                                                            options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                            error:NULL];

                                        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image"
                                                            fileName:@"image.jpg" 
                                                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                                            
                                        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"letterhead"
                                                            fileName:@"image.jpg" 
                                                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                        
                                        [formData appendPartWithFormData:myData name:@"offerDTO"];
                                    }
                                ];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];     
    }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, NSError error)
    {    
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
         
    }
];
```

Comment: You'll have better luck getting help if we could see what was tried so far and specifics on what is not working.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rob Please have a look at the code above. I guess its on same lines you suggested, but still no luck. :(

Comment: @Frankie Please have a look at the code now.

Comment: And what happens when you run this code (assuming of course, you `start` the request, or enqueue it on the `AFHTTPClient`, or add it to an operation queue)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Your example is AFNetworking 1.x. AFNetworking 3.x rendition might look like:

   ```
   NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"1" withExtension:@"png"];

   // If you need to build dictionary dynamically as in your question, that's fine,
   // but sometimes array literals are more concise way if the structure of
   // the dictionary is always the same.

   // Also note that these keys do _not_ match what are present in the `curl`
   // so please double check these keys (e.g. `discountDiscription` vs
   // `discountDescription` vs `name`)!

   NSDictionary *offerDTO = @{@"code"                : @"",
                              @"discountDescription" : @"Testing",
                              @"remark"              : @"Test",
                              @"validityDate"        : @"07-05-2015",
                              @"creatorCode"         : @"C-7",
                              @"merchantCode"        : @"M-1",
                              @"isApproved"          : @YES,
                              @"discountValue"       : @2.4,
                              @"discountType"        : @"FREE"};

   // `AFHTTPSessionManager` is AFNetworking 3.x equivalent to `AFHTTPClient` in AFNetworking 1.x

   NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serverurl:8180"];
   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

   // The `POST` method both creates and issues the request

   [manager POST:@"/restapi/offer/add" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
       NSError *error;
       BOOL success;

       success = [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL
                                            name:@"image"
                                        fileName:@"image.jpg"
                                        mimeType:@"image/png"
                                           error:&error];
       NSAssert(success, @"Failure adding file: %@", error);

       success = [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL
                                            name:@"letterhead"
                                        fileName:@"image.jpg"
                                        mimeType:@"image/png"
                                           error:&error];
       NSAssert(success, @"Failure adding file: %@", error);

       NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:offerDTO options:0 error:&error];
       NSAssert(jsonData, @"Failure building JSON: %@", error);

       // You could just do:
       //
       // [formData appendPartWithFormData:jsonData name:@"offerDTO"];
       //
       // but I now notice that in your `curl`, you set the `Content-Type` for the
       // part, so if you want to do that, you could do it like so:

       NSDictionary *jsonHeaders = @{@"Content-Disposition" : @"form-data; name=\"offerDTO\"",
                                     @"Content-Type"        : @"application/json"};
       [formData appendPartWithHeaders:jsonHeaders body:jsonData];
   } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
       // do whatever you want here
   } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
   } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
       NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
   }];
   ```
2. You are creating an operation here, but never add it to a queue to start it. I assume you do that elsewhere. It's worth noting that `AFHTTPSessionManager` doesn't support operations like the deprecated `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` or `AFHTTPClient` used to. The above code just starts the operation automatically.
3. Note, AFNetworking now assumes the response will be JSON. Given that your code suggests the response is JSON, then note that no `JSONObjectWithData` is needed, as that's done for you already.
4. Right now your code is (a) creating `UIImage`; (b) converting it back to a `NSData`; and (c) adding that to the `formData`. That is inefficient for a number of reasons:

   - Specifically, by taking the image asset, loading it into a `UIImage`, and then using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, you may be making the resulting `NSData` considerably larger than the original asset. You might consider just grabbing the original asset, bypassing `UIImage` altogether, and sending that (obviously, if you're sending PNG, then change the mime-type, too).
   - The process of adding `NSData` to the request can result in larger memory footprint. Often if you supply a file name, it can keep the peak memory usage a bit lower.

Comment: Thanks Rob, your answer solved the issue. Really appreciate it!! :)

Comment: @Rob how to do this using alamofire?

Comment: @Nullify - See "Uploading Multipart Form Data" section of [Uploading Data to a Server](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-data-to-a-server). The conceptual idea would be the same as the above. I'd suggest you give it a good faith effort on your part, and if you have questions, post your own question, showing us what you tried.

Comment: For the sake of transparency, I must confess that I'm not 100% crazy about this pattern of JSON in a x-www-form-urlencoded request. There's nothing technically wrong with it, but it just feels architecturally muddled. It seems that one should go one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

you  can pass your NSdictionary directly to manger post block in parametersfield

```
UIImage *imageToPost = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);

NSDictionary *offerDTO = @{@"code"                : @"",
                           @"discountDescription" : @"Testing",
                           @"remark"              : @"Test",
                           @"validityDate"        : @"07-05-2015",
                           @"creatorCode"         : @"C-7",
                           @"merchantCode"        : @"M-1",
                           @"isApproved"          : @YES,
                           @"discountValue"       : @2.4,
                           @"discountType"        : @"FREE"};

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serverurl:8180"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[manager POST:@"/restapi/offer/add" parameters:offerDTO constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image"
                            fileName:@"image.jpg"
                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"letterhead"
                            fileName:@"image.jpg"
                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];


    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:jsonHeaders body:jsonData];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}]
```

;